# AppEngine - Blobstore API: How to solve the "The API call file.Create() took too long to respond and was cancelled." bug?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am currently using the Google AppEngine Blobstore API to store and access files on my Java GAE-powered website.

My website (that also serves as a backend to a mobile app) has been online for a couple weeks now and everything was working fine, but since today I am having an issue on each call to the Blobstore .create() or .open() API.

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApiDeadlineExceededException: The API call file.Create() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1495)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:237)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.makeSyncCall(Recorder.java:329)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:101)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:586)
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.create(FileServiceImpl.java:498)
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.createNewBlobFile(FileServiceImpl.java:103)
```

I have a similar issue to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387257/appengine-java-the-api-call-file-create-took-too-long-to-respond-and-was-canc), except that it is now *always* happening.

I saw a couple bugs report on the Appengine website, most of them are closed or have been inactive for quite long.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?
I know this API is supposed to be experimental so I am also wondering if I should rather use the Google Cloud Storage API instead (which is also experimental).

Thanks for your input

Comment: This happens when some of the GAE services have limite availability (Blobstore in this case). This usually goes away in minutes.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but this has been going on for 12h+ now